# Moving from ElasticSearch to OpenSearch in PHP Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch, opensearch, aiven

We are currently using ElasticSearch with PHP Symfony which is hosted by Aiven but Aiven currently no longer offers Elasticsearch. This offer is replaced by OpenSearch 1.0. So, Aiven plans to migrate all existing ElasticSearch projects to OpenSearch by March 2022 at the latest.

At the moment we are using the 'Elastica' package by Ruflin. Using the same package should probably work but we need to find a new package since Elastica will not support any forked instances of ElasticSearch (reference: https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/issues/1962).

However, it seems there isn't a package that will support the OpenSearch forked instance from ElasticSearch. Anyone in the same situation at the moment, please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Since OpenSearch is compatible with ElasticSearch 7.10, you can pin your dependencies at the current versions, and you should be able to safely migrate. On Aiven, you can fork your Elasticsearch to create an as-live upgraded OpenSearch instance to check that things do work before you press the upgrade button on your production platform. This means that you can get future upgrades and security fixes, but if the projects diverge and Elastic doesn't support the open source features, then at some time in the future you might need to move away from the Elastic library.

Answer (score 0):

You can get opensearch-php, the official library from Opensearch here:

https://github.com/opensearch-project/opensearch-php

Or you can load it via composer:

> "opensearch-project/opensearch-php"

Quote from opensearch-php:

> opensearch-php is a community-driven, open source fork of
> elasticsearch-php licensed under the Apache v2.0 License. For more
> information, see opensearch.org.